# How to keep the value of angle between 0 and PI in box2d

Tags: box2d, angles

In box2d, if i rotate an object multiple times in clockwise or anti clockwise direction, the value of angle ( body.getAngle() ) keeps on increasing. Like at start it is at 0 radians, then 1.57(90 deg), after complete roatation 6.28, then after second rotation 2*6.28 .
If a player keeps on rotating for too much time, angle value becomes really big.And for multiplayer games, sending big values uses more bytes.

How can i keep the value between 0 to +-3.14.Is there any solution in box2d Or
Is it a good way of sending Sin(angle) to keep the value between -1 and 1 and doing reverse of sin at client side.

Comment: This sounds like something you can solve by just doing a modulo on the angle before you send it, no Box2D-specific solution required, just vanilla math. Where have you run into trouble wrapping this angle in your netcode?

Comment: I guess updating the box2d body angle using modulo( angle %= 2*pi) will be better.

Answer (score 1):

For better or worse, unbounded, non-normalized, angles are a property of the body's sweep. When calling [`b2Body::GetAngle()`](https://github.com/erincatto/box2d/blob/9ebbbcd960ad424e03e5de6e66a40764c16f51bc/include/box2d/b2_body.h#L175), that's what you're actually getting (see [line 491](https://github.com/erincatto/box2d/blob/9ebbbcd960ad424e03e5de6e66a40764c16f51bc/include/box2d/b2_body.h#L491)).

If you want bounded, normalized angles, you can perform a modulo operation on this angle as has been suggested before in the comments.

Alternatively, you can also use the angle from the rotational portion of the body's transformation. Call [`b2Body::GetTransform()`](https://github.com/erincatto/box2d/blob/9ebbbcd960ad424e03e5de6e66a40764c16f51bc/include/box2d/b2_body.h#L167) to get the transform and invoke `q.GetAngle()` on that. So if you have a pointer called `b` that's to a body you're interested in getting the normalized, bounded angle for, the code would look like:

```
b->GetTransform().q.GetAngle()
```

Between these two techniques, doing the modulo math on the sweep angle may be faster than the `std::atan2` that using the rotational portion of the transform requires (at least it has been in the bench-marking I've done). OTOH, doing the modulo math may also be less accurate.

Allowing the sweep angle to grow unbounded is a ticking time bomb of floating point math however. This angle's going to get less and less accurate much the way scrolling does for linear values.

To work around this growing imprecision, you may also want to normalize the sweep angle (by doing something like calling `b2Body::SetTransform`). Note however that this can cause odd behavior in joints like gear joints. There doesn't seem like an ideal solution to me. So just understand the issues/trade-offs.